# Conda can't install package from *.txt

Tags: python, anaconda, package, conda

I installed Anaconda and some packages which I get both from *conda-forge* & *pip*

I have export it with this command

```
conda list --explicit > explicit_packageslist.txt
```

Now, I want make identical environment from that file

```
conda create --name myenv --file explicit_packageslist.txt
```

I have error like this

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

What should I do?

*edit : please download this file :
[explicit_packageslist](https://github.com/conda/conda/files/6911201/explicit_packageslist.txt)

Comment: Why is your package list so enormous?

Comment: because I want all in one environment

Comment: That's quite the opposite of what environments are designed for.